# Search and combine several dict with same key, sum values

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I get a list of ingredients from menu dict
In that list, for each menu item several dicts with several ingredients:

```
{'ingredient_name': 'A', 'measure': 'kg', 'quantity': 1}
{'ingredient_name': 'B', 'measure': 'ml', 'quantity': 50}
{'ingredient_name': 'A', 'measure': 'kg', 'quantity': 2}
{'ingredient_name': 'C', 'measure': 'count', 'quantity': 2}
...
```

The output should be like that:

```
{
A: {'measure': 'kg', 'quantity': 3},
B: {'measure': 'ml', 'quantity': 50},
C: {'measure': 'count', 'quantity': 2}
}
```

Currently I cannot find the way to combine matching ingredients, it only shows the last one with duplicate name. If I .append all in a list, list.count(y) > 2, it still ignores the first instance. Keep in mind there are several dicts, it is a function with potential 50+ items.

Function part:

```
  ingridients_dict = {key: cook_book[key] for key in dishes}
  for items in ingridients_dict.values():
    for ingredients in items:
      x = ingredients['quantity'] * person_count
      ingredients.update({'quantity': x})
      final_list[ingridients.pop('ingredient_name')] = ingredients
  return final_list

pprint(shop_list([dishes], person_count: int), indent=1, width=70)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question right. You can try:

```py
lst = [
    {"ingredient_name": "A", "measure": "kg", "quantity": 1},
    {"ingredient_name": "B", "measure": "ml", "quantity": 50},
    {"ingredient_name": "A", "measure": "kg", "quantity": 2},
    {"ingredient_name": "C", "measure": "count", "quantity": 2},
]

out = {}
for d in lst:
    out.setdefault(d["ingredient_name"], {}).update(measure=d["measure"])
    out[d["ingredient_name"]]["quantity"] = (
        out[d["ingredient_name"]].get("quantity", 0) + d["quantity"]
    )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "A": {"measure": "kg", "quantity": 3},
    "B": {"measure": "ml", "quantity": 50},
    "C": {"measure": "count", "quantity": 2},
}
```

Comment: oh thank you! yes it works. the issue was about "for items in ingridients_dict.values():" items list had several ingridients for one dish. I had to go through ingredients in items, create list.append(ingredients) and then count them. I tried to count items list, guess it was the main issue why it didn't work, it counted only ingr_dict in one list.

Answer (score 0):

```
  final_list = {}
  cook_book = makecookbook(recipe_file) ## function creating dict based on recipe.txt, with key = cook_book['dish'], value = list of ingredients 
  ingredients_dict = {key: cook_book[key] for key in dishes}
  for items in ingriedients_dict.values():
    for ingredients in items:
      final_list.setdefault(ingredients["ingredient_name"], {}).update(measure=ingredients["measure"])
      final_list[ingredients["ingredient_name"]]["quantity"] = (
        final_list[ingredients["ingredient_name"]].get("quantity", 0) + ingredients["quantity"] * person_count)
  return final_list


pprint(shop_list_by_dish(['xxx', 'yyy', 'vvv'], person_count), indent=1, width=70)
```